# Add property sheet in Active directory user obejct

Tags: c#, c++, active-directory

I searched a lot in google to find a good documentation in how to add an own property sheet for an active directory user object.
Some of the documentation is outdated and does not work with 64-bit systems.

What I would like to do is, to add some extra information which are not stored in the AD and needs to be gathered from other systems, so ADExplorer by sysinternals or ADSI will not help at this point. These information must be displayed within the property dialog of an AD user object. An external app is not an option.

Does anybody know a good link or maybe a good example (C++ or C# would be nice) in how to create a custom property sheet for this dialog?

Answer (score 0):

In the 'Microsoft Platform SDK for Windows Server 2003 R2' is a sample console project in C++ called 'PropSheetHost' which opens the property sheet for an Active Directory objects.